# How do you serialize non-standard JSON with JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am accessing a third-party vendors web service to obtain client data.  The problem is, the JSON is not formatted within a consistently named hierarchy, making working with it very difficult.  Here is a sample of the structure of the data:

```
{
   "0": {
      "account": {
         "id": 97657
      },
      "warehouse": {
         "sid": "9999"
      },
      "special": {
         "value_one": "306"
      }
   },
   "1": {
      "account": {
         "id": 97722
      },
      "warehouse": {
         "sid": "9999"
      },
      "special": {
         "value_one": "444"
      }
   },
   "2": {
      "account": {
         "id": 88843
      },
      "warehouse": {
         "sid": "9999"
      },
      "special": {
         "value_one": "222"
      }
   },       
   "errno": 0,
   "errmsg": "Operation completed with no errors"
}
```

I have tried numerous methods to parse through the data, but nothing is working.  The only success I have had is by manually typing in the path, like such:

```
JObject objJson = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader)); 
string id = (string)objJson["0"]["account"]["id"];
string sid = (string)objJson["0"]["warehouse"]["sid"];
```

Trying anything dynamic throws error "Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected."

```
for (int i = 0; i < objJson.Count; i++)
{                
   string id = (string)objJson[i]["account"]["id"];                    
}
```

UPDATE: Other questions of this type have a common parent.  This one does not.

Comment: try using "objJson[i.ToString()]" - 0 and "0" are two very different indexers

Comment: Flag the question instead of post link

Comment: chambo, objJson[i.ToString()] throws :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please explain how this is a duplicate.  In the "duplicate" there is a root called "files"  My root is an index that can be any number.